# changing src after page load / is executable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A. I wondering how to change  src after page load using Javascript

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.png" /> to <img src="http://domain.com/different.jpg" />
```

B. My second question to follow is - will the the new src of the image (domain.com/different.jpg) will be displayed? it will execute a new network request?

Comment: yes, you can change the src of an image (or pretty much anything) on a page during/after load, and the new source will be loaded/processed/displayed.

Comment: There is anyway to avoid a new network request?

Comment: consider this: you order Combo #B at a fast food place, then just as they're putting it onto the tray you change your mind and order Combo #C. Do you think they can magically turn that burger B into soup C at the counter, without going back to the kitchen? If they have an unclaimed C at the counter (your browser cache), then yes, you can avoid a network request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery and write the below code after document ready

A. `$('img').attr('src','http://domain.com/different.jpg');`

B. Yes, the image will display and yes, it will execute a new network request

Answer (score 0):

A: This would need to be done client-side (presumably by some javascript).

B: Yes; Any change to a resource's location would (if not already cached) involve another round-trip.